# Error LNK1169, Help!! I'm a beginner

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I was given a code to look for error and fix it. But I don't know why I can't run it. it keeps saying "fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

This is the original code that i have to fix.

```
int value1, int value2, int value3 ;
FILE outptr;
outptr=fopen(“myfile.txt”, ‘w’);
if(outptr)
{
Printf(outptr, “ %f %f %f” , value1, value2, value3)
};
fclose(outptr);
else
{
fprintf(“The file myfile.txt is not available”);
}
```

And this is what i came up with

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int value1, value2, value3;
    FILE *outptr;
    outptr = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");


    if(outptr)

    {
    printf("please put in values for value1,value2,value3\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&value1, &value2, &value3);
    fprintf(outptr, "%d %d %d", value1, value2, value3);
    fclose(outptr);
    }

    else
    {
    printf("The file is not available");
    }

}
```

but I keep getting error LNK1169. Please help me.

Comment: Um, the code is OK. Your problem seems to be elsewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error+LNK1169

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with your project where you have a repeated function with the same name (possibly even multiple main()s). When compiling your compiler is finding a repeated function and thus complaining that you have declared it twice. Try removing this code and placing it into a separate new project and you may find it passes in isolation.

EDIT: I just found this [error definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xttf5w7w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which confirms my suspicion.